# Running commandline applications with PHP

Tags: php, command-line

How can I successfully run commandline applications from PHP on a linux/Mac system.

I'm using a mac and trying to run optipng. I've downloaded optipng from here

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/optipng/files/OptiPNG/optipng-0.7.5/optipng-0.7.5.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=softlayer-sng&download=
```

After downloading it, I installed it via the command line by CD'ing to the download folder, and installing it accordingly:

```
cd path/to/optipng
sudo ./configure
sudo make install
```

I can now run it and compress images like this:

```
optipng path/to/example/file.png
```

Everything works fine so it's installed and working on my system.

I want to run it via a php page so i try this:

```
<?php
echo "origional size =". filesize(path/to/example/file.png)."\n";

$compress = shell_exec('optipng path/to/example/file.png');

echo "<pre>$compress</pre>";

echo "new size =". filesize(path/to/example/file.png)."\n";

?>
```

But it does nothing. What am I missing here? How do I use shell_exec() or exec() successfully?

Comment: `var_dump($compress);` after shell_exec. What is in it ?

Comment: do optipng require any environment variable ?

Comment: all it needs is the path to the file.

Comment: Use absolute paths rather than relative ones.

Comment: what is the output of your php file?

Comment: origional size =85424 new size =85424

Comment: Very likely, you need to specify the full path to the executable `shell_exec('/path/to/optipng /path/to/target/file.png')`

Comment: Even though you ran `make install` which probably placed it somewhere like `/usr/local/bin`, PHP may not have a `$PATH` defined, and therefore fails to find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
exec('/dev/null > /tmp/optipng.log');
echo "origional size =". filesize('/tmp/steve-jobs.png')."\n";

shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/optipng -log /tmp/optipng.log /tmp/steve-jobs.png');
$compress = file_get_contents('/tmp/optipng.log');

echo "<pre>$compress</pre>";

echo "new size =". filesize('/tmp/steve-jobs.png')."\n";

?>
```